# Access a COM Interface method C++

Tags: c++, com, oleview

Both:

- CLSID
- IID

Having specified the above, and using:

- CoCreateInstance()

To returning a single uninitialised object of the class specified by the CLSID above.

How can I then access an Interface's method from C++?
Without:

- ATL
- MFC
- Just plain C++

Afterwards, I use CreateInstance()

I'm having trouble, using CreateInstance() - with the last parameter - ppv

Using oleview, I can see methods of the specified IIDabove IID above, such as:

```
interface IS8Simulation : IDispatch {
    HRESULT Open([in] BSTR FileName);
};
```

How can I then access the above? Examples/guidance - please

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By doing a CoCreateInstance you get an interface pointer. Through QueryInterface(...) method you can get the interface pointer of some other interface easily.
e.g.,

```
IUnknown* pUnk = NULL;
HRESULT hr = ::CoCreateInstance(clsid,NULL,CLSCTX_ALL,__uuidof(IUnknown),(void**)&pUnk);
```

IS8Simulation* pSim = NULL;
hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IS8Simulation), (void**)&pSim);

After doing this, you will get the pointer to IS8Simulation in pSim and through that you can call methods of that interface. Remember you need to provide a valid clsid in the CoCreateInstance call.

Comment: In the example, both the uuidof(..) calls should be preceeded by double underscores. I added that but somehow those are lost in formatting ( I should have escaped those probably)

Comment: Aamir +1 for a good post, but rather than commenting on your own posts you are better to edit them.  Keeps it clear for those just scannng through posts without looking at comments.

Comment: Thanks Aamir, but - where is - IS8Simulation declared? How can I call methods from that interface, that contain parameters such as BSTR (illustrated above)

Comment: well... using Oleview you can see the typelib information of the interface. This will tell you that from which binary the interface is coming from. It is normally something like win32 = 'something.dll'. This is the dll/tlb etc. which normally contains the declaration of this interface.

Comment: I got the following compiler errors:

`IS8Simulation' undeclared (first use this function)
`pSim' undeclared (first use this function)
`__uuidof' undeclared (first use this function)

Comment: Don't forget to Release http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682317(VS.85).aspx the interface pointer! Otherwise you will have memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little vague what the actual problem is.  Some code would be helpful.  But to take a guess, do you need to QueryInterface?

Answer (score 0):

```
 IS8Simulation* pSim = NULL;
 hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IS8Simulation), (void)&pSim);
```

I'll attempt the above, but were is IS8Simulation declared - please excuss my lack of **COM** understanding

Furthermore, how to call the method, below using **plain C++**:

```
HRESULT Open([in] BSTR FileName)
```

Comment: once you have pointer to your interface i.e., pSim in above example, you can call its methods simply like..

BSTR bstrFileName = ::SysAllocString(fileName);
hr = pSim->Open(bstrFileName);

Remember to free the BSTR after using by calling ::SysFreeString()
And yes, this is plain C++

Comment: Aamir, thanks again!!! :) I'll attempt the above, and will post my finding - you've been a big help wow!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want #import "something.dll". This will give you C++ declarations for types like IS8Simulation, similar to what #include "something.h" would do.

Comment: I'm in the process of trying to compile IDL FILE using MIDL Compiler. I found type declarations like "single" (which is VB) - is this normal?